# Is JSON.parse efficient for huge data(50+MB)?

Tags: node.js, json, database

I was making my android app using firebase realtime data storage. But their pricing was too high so I decided to shift to the NodeJS server. But I am new to NodeJS...

Firebase realtime stores in JSON format, so I extracted it and ran it in the NodeJS server. But the file is gradually growing big and I am worried if JSON.parse() will be inefficient for querying each request. Currently, it seems to be working fine with ~1MB(56k lines) of JSON data.

UPDATE(for understanding)
This is sample code for Node

```
http.createServer(options,function (req, res){
    // Set a response type of plain text for the response
    try{
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain/html; charset=utf-8'});
      var out=""
      requrl=req.url.substring(1)
      console.log(Date().toString()+" "+req.url)     
      mode=path.substring(0,path.indexOf("/"))
      path=path.substring(path.indexOf("/")+1)             
      if(mode=="r"){
        fs.readFile('data.json', "utf-8", (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            jdata= JSON.parse(data); //PARSING WHOLE DATA   
            try{
              sendData = getData(path,jdata) //GETTING THE REQUESTED DATA
            } 
            catch(err){
              console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`)
            }
            res.write(`${JSON.stringify(sendData)}`)        
            return res.end();
        });
      }
   }
}).listen(//MyServer);
```

and I am sending a request from the Android App. I just need to parse the requested data but for that currently, I need to parse the whole JSON data. So I am worried if parsing whole data would be inefficient or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "if JSON.parse() will be inefficient for querying each request"? JSON.parse as the name indicates, parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by string. If it is efficient or not, guess depends on the browser implementation.

Comment: @abestrad check the updated post!

Comment: @G.OVed so you will **not** be using firebase. How will you be updating the stored JSON? the same way parse, update in memory, save the stringified new object ? Why not use something like mongoDB ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli yeah going with Mongo now! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Node.js single thread feature it is not that good to handle CPU bound tasks. e.g. calculation or large data encode and decode

You can try this module 
https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify

Or using `Fork`, `child process`, `worker thread` to handle this.